# SPF and importance "a", "ptr" and "mx"

Tags: spf

Let's say I have three domains:

domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com

For each, I have the following SPF records:

```
domain1.com
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:y.y.y.y include:domain2.com ~all

domain2.com
v=spf1 ip4:c.c.c.c ip4:d.d.d.d include:domain3.com ~all

domain3.com
v=spf1 ip4:.e.e.e.e ip4:f.f.f.f ~all
```

Now, I am sending my email from following domains:

MFROM (return-path): test@test-a.com
PRA (from): test@test-b.com

For these two domains, I have following SPF:

```
test-a.com:
v=spf1 redirect=domain1.com

test-b.com
v=spf1 include:domain1.com ~all
```

When I test this structure through SPF test tools, it passes. But I wonder if adding "a" and "mx" to the SPF record of domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com will increase Hotmail/Yahoo/Gmail/AOL inbox delivery success.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks.

Mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's.. convoluted.  A device wishing to validate SPF on one of the test domains will need to do four different record lookups; I would not be surprised if some of the MTAs in use by those organizations capped their lookups to something lower.

Why not just keep it simple, and avoid having to ask yourself if service providers will put up with your numerous includes?

```
domain1.com
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x ip4:y.y.y.y ip4:c.c.c.c ip4:d.d.d.d ip4:e.e.e.e ip4:f.f.f.f ~all

domain2.com
v=spf1 ip4:c.c.c.c ip4:d.d.d.d ip4:e.e.e.e ip4:f.f.f.f ~all

domain3.com
v=spf1 ip4:e.e.e.e ip4:f.f.f.f ~all

test-a.com:
v=spf1 redirect=domain1.com

test-b.com
v=spf1 redirect=domain1.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. I am going to merge all SPF's into one big SPF on domain1.com

Comment: but what about "a" and "mx" parameters in the SPF record. Should I also add them?

Comment: If the host definitions that you have already cover the senders that need to be authorized, then there's no need; the ip4 rules are sufficient.